# How to overlay PDFs with InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector, text, adobe-acrobat

I have the following Text in one PDF file,

http://www.docdroid.net/10053/22.pdf.html

and want to insert it in following Border PDF File:

http://www.docdroid.net/1004w/110.pdf.html

in such a way that background of text is omitted. I try Clipping Path for remove background but because we have font, some margin of font is distored !!! how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution using Acrobat only (as it is mentioned in your tags).

1. open your border PDF in Acrobat
2. go to `pages > watermark > Add Watermark`
3. select file and choose your second PDF text file
4. adjust the scale and the position as you wish and press Ok.
5. save the result to a new PDF

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place the background PDF.

Then place the text PDF on top of the background PDF.

With the text PDF selected, set the **blending mode** on the **Effects Panel** (`Window > Effects`) to `Multiply`.

Answer (score -1):

In Adobe Indesign, we usually put the omitting backgrounds in Master Pages or A-Master, it's on the top right placed inside "Pages" tab (if your using the default Essentials workspace). See the youtube link below to understand using the Master Pages.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsl4-J-h8jc

Go and explore! :)
-Sai